# Opportunity records are shared with users automatically

Tags: visualforce, apex-managed-sharing, apex-sharing, sharerecord

We are using a Visualforce page for creating Opportunity records. The Opportunity OWD is set to Private.We have salespersons field(users) being set on Opportunity Page while creating Opportunity. The Opportunity will be shared to these users through Apex Sharing. The code just fethes the users selected on VF page and gives read/Write access.The process is working fine as expected. However for few cases, the records are shared to other users who aren't mentioned on page( includes users of different profiles/roles). This sharing doesn't happen during record creation or editing of record.

Does any one came across such issue..?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please check your sharing records by clicking on share button, and see what is the reason of sharing getting done. That would help you analyze the root cause.

Comment: The reason shows: 'Manual Sharing'. However in system, the record is never shared manually. Not sure how the manual share is fired and record is being shared.

Comment: Then it means someone has manually shared by clicking on share button on that opportunity. There is no other reason for the same. You just test it with 5-10 opportunity records, and if all works fine, then it will be clear that someone else has shared the record manually. I am putting this in answers as well, if this helps you, accept the answer, so that it help other members in future for similar kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments:

If the reason of sharing is showing as **Manual Sharing** then it means that someone has manually shared by clicking on the **Share** button on that opportunity. There is no other reason for the same. You just test it with 5-10 opportunity records, and if all works fine, then it will be clear that someone else has shared the record manually.

Comment: We have tested multiple scenarios. The record is shared to a single user along with owner. None among these 2 clicked on share button. But the opportunity share list shows multiple people added to list after couple of days.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be possible. There may be some other process happening or some other admin might have clicked on share button to share the record.

Comment: I am the admin. I have shared the record to single user. The share button displayed on 2 users over there(Me-Owner and the other user). The other user didn't login for next 1 week and I didn't share the record to any other user. However after a week, there were 6-7 new users when clicked on share button on same record. The reason mentioned over there is:'Manual Sharing'. Not sure how it is triggered.

Comment: You should test now with only brand new records and deactivate other users(if possible) and then test. Otherwise no other reason to have this manual sharing records.

Comment: The above scenario was for a brand new record. Was created and shared with single user. the share button showed only 2 users in it as expected. However after few days there were multiple new users added to list.